# How to clear javascript SessionStorage in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, session-storage

I have a system where I save temporary variables using sessionStorage (javascript).

How can I do to clean them in C # inside a controller?

Tried `HttpContext.Session.Clear()`

But I was unsuccessful, the variable remains active until I close the browser.

Comment: C# runs server-side.  javascript runs client-side.  The server can not reach into the client and start poking around.  You'll need to emit the proper js onto your page that accomplishes your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Sam Axe's answer.

HttpContext.Session.Clear() is .NET context (server side). The sessionStorage is JavaScript, so you have to call:

sessionStorage.clear();

on the client side, so in the JavaScript code, possibly on some event button click, etc.)

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I adapted the program to clean via javascript, thanks a lot for the answer.